# ASP.Net Core - Web API to get accessed via PowerBI and Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, powerbi

I'm creating a custom ASP.Net Corw 3.1 Web App with some APIs, one of which should get accessed from PowerBI.
As PowerBI should be used via organizational account, I would like to configure everyting so the user can use the account.

On the backend, I'm setting up the OpenIDConnect like defined in the Microsoft documentation

```
services
    .AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

And I protect the controller accordingly:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class SomeCOntroller : ControllerBase
```

On the Azure App Registration, I also define the app in the Azure Active Directory:
[image]

When I now navigate to the REST API via browser, I get redirected accoringly to the organization login and can use my account, getting navigated back to the API.

But PowerBI insists, that the authentication type is is not supported:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Checking the sign-ins on Azure, I don't see any request coming from the PowerBI, just the ones from the web. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is there some specific logic needed for PowerBI? Unfortunately, the error form PowerBI doesn't hit anything on that topic and as the access via Web works, I would guess the setup is correct as well?

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: Probably I've missunderstood the link, but it didn't explain anything about authorization / authentication? Also, passing tokens via header doesn't make too much sense, as a user isn't capable of creating tokens by itself. I had to go back to basic auth for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication setup of Web API seems to be correct. But, the testing part looks incorrect as you are not passing Access token in the header. Check out [Call REST APIs And Parse JSON With Power BI](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/power-bi-report-generation-through-web) for tutorial on how to call REST APIs from Power BI.

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Hm thank you for the feedback, but I don't get an access token isn't it? It's a OAuth2 Authentication Code flow, which is set up by the backend AppID / Secret? The link doesn't say much about the authentication, but it would be really odd, if one would need to set headers manually?

Comment: Without access token you cannot call AD authenticated API. There is an option MSI, but this is just for Azure resources. Moreover, the above link is for testing purposes only. Are you not testing the flow? Pls correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Well, my ultimate goal is to secure an API with Azure AD and a appropriate flow, so that users get redirected to the Azure AD Login and can use the recpetive Azure AD login. I would guess this is authentication code (as my backend can securely store a secret).I've used the quickstart-guide for the respetive scenario (web app) and it works for the web, as the user gets redirected to the Azure AD login and back to my app, but not for PowerBI.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood question. Pls check out: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/azure-active-directory-meets-power-bi/

Comment: Also this: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/azure-active-directory-and-power-bi/